# DatetimePicker is not a function

Tags: html, bootstrap, datetimepicker

Intento replicar el DateTimePicker de esta pagina https://getdatepicker.com/4/ Necesito el DateTimePicker con la hora, pero ya tome el codigo html asi como el script y me manda este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo:

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="col-sm-6" style="height:130px;">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker8'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="fa fa-calendar">
            </span>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
          $('#datetimepicker8').datetimepicker({
              icons: {
                  time: "fa fa-clock-o",
                  date: "fa fa-calendar",
                  up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
                  down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
              }
          });
      });
   </script>
</div>
```

Me estaran faltando algunos script de bootstrap?, en mi pagina se mira asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Claro, te falta todo la seccion header donde van los scripts... en la sección INSTALLING menciona los que debes añadir.

Comment: Falta que agregues los javascript de la biblioteca como lo indica [https://getdatepicker.com/4/Installing](https://getdatepicker.com/4/Installing)